# calculate mantissa and exponent of scientific number in matlab

Tags: matlab, exponent, mantissa

I want to find mantissa and exponent of a number in mat lab. Is there a function or way to calculate them?

for example when the number is 0.0005 this function returns 5 for mantissa and -4 for exponent

thank you

Comment: your Mantissa seems to deviate from Wolfram's definition http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponent can be given by :

```
x= 0.0005;
exponent=floor(log10(x));
```

and the coefficient (I refuse to call it mantissa, because it disagrees with common definition).

```
coeff=x/10^exponent;
```